# How do I call my data service from my REST API and redirect to a URL on Enterprise Integrator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

I have created a data service on Enterprise Integrator that searches a microsoft sql server database for a usercode, if the usercode I am searching for exists in the db the response is the users first name and last name. Is it possible for the user to get redirected to a c# webpage instead of their first name and last name being returned?
I am then calling my data service with my rest api, my intention is to search an microsft sql db and if the data is in the db I should be redirected to a c# webpage. However when I try to test my API I am getting back my json from the Result (Output Mapping) in my query from my data service. I am unsure how to resolve the conflict and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

My Data Service Code:

`

```
<data name="restds" transports="http https">
   <config enableOData="false" id="restdb">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">REST</property>
   </config>
   <query id="query2" useConfig="restdb">
      <sql>select UserCode,FirstName,LastName from UserDB.dbo.Users where UserCode=?</sql>
      <result outputType="json" useColumnNumbers="true"> {&#xd;"users": {&#xd;"user": [&#xd; {&#xd; "UserCode": "$1",&#xd; "FirstName": "$2",&#xd; "LastName": "$3"&#xd; }&#xd; ]&#xd; }&#xd;}      &#xd;         &#xd;      </result>
      <param name="UserCode" optional="false" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <resource method="GET" path="Users">
      <call-query href="query2">
         <with-param name="UserCode" query-param="UserCode"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
</data>
```

My REST API Code:

```
`<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DSAPI2" context="/dsapi2">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{UserCode}">
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/restds/Users"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <filter xpath="$body//FirstName/text() != ''">
            <then>
               <log>
                  <property name="Message" value="Name Exists Lets redirect"/>
               </log>
               <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="Location" value="https://wso2.com/" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log>
                  <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302"/>
                  <property name="Location" value="https://www.youtube.com/"/>
               </log>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
       `
```

I was expecting to redirect when testing the API, however the response body I am getting is:

```
{
  "users": {}
}
```

Which is from the json in my data service

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in the dataservice. In REST API on Integration studio, while you get successful response, you can use HTTP redirect 302. Use property `HTTP_SC` with 302 code and http header with `Location` like below:

```
<property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="302"/>
<property name="Location" value="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
```

You can set the `Location` address to your c# website.
But I am not sure, if that that solution is not too awkward.

See docs:
[Web/HTTP/Redirections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) and [Web/HTTP/Headers/Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location)

Comment: Hi thank you for your feedback, when I tried to create a REST API on Integration Studio it was giving a failed response, I will edit the API code into my post above.

Answer (score 1):

As tmoasz mentioned. You can't do it in the Dataservice, what you can do is interface the Dataservice with an API and handle the redirection logic there. You don't have to use DbLookup or additional mediators to connect to the DB. Simply call your Dataservice from the API. Something like below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/checkuser" name="YOURAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/rcsrest/Users">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <filter xpath="$body//FirstName/text() != ''">
                <then>
                    <log>
                        <property name="Message" value="Name Exists Lets redirect"/>
                    </log>
                    <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="302"/>
                    <property name="Location" value="https://to-someplace" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <log>
                        <property name="Message" value="Name is empty no redirection"/>
                    </log>
                </else>
            </filter>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

---

**Update**
Adding the Query Param to the Payload.

Note: GET request will not allow you to send Payloads in the request body, hence change the Dataservice method to a `POST` as well.

**Dataservice**

```xml
<data name="restds" transports="http https">
   <config enableOData="false" id="restdb">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">REST</property>
   </config>
   <query id="query2" useConfig="restdb">
      <sql>select UserCode,FirstName,LastName from UserDB.dbo.Users where UserCode=?</sql>
      <result outputType="json" useColumnNumbers="true"> {&#xd;"users": {&#xd;"user": [&#xd; {&#xd; "UserCode": "$1",&#xd; "FirstName": "$2",&#xd; "LastName": "$3"&#xd; }&#xd; ]&#xd; }&#xd;}      &#xd;         &#xd;      </result>
      <param name="UserCode" optional="false" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <resource method="POST" path="Users">
      <call-query href="query2">
         <with-param name="UserCode" query-param="UserCode"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
</data>
```

**API**

```xml
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DSAPI2" context="/dsapi2">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{UserCode}">
      <inSequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                  <body xmlns="">
                      <p:_getusers xmlns:p="ws.wso2.org/dataservice/query2">
                          <xs:UserCode xmlns:xs="ws.wso2.org/dataservice/query2">$1</xs:UserCode>
                      </p:_getusers>
                  </body>
              </format>
              <args>
                  <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$url:UserCode"/>
              </args>
          </payloadFactory>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="POST" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/restds/Users"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <filter xpath="$body//FirstName/text() != ''">
            <then>
               <log>
                  <property name="Message" value="Name Exists Lets redirect"/>
               </log>
               <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="Location" value="https://wso2.com/" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log>
                  <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302"/>
                  <property name="Location" value="https://www.youtube.com/"/>
               </log>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Hi I have tried implementing this API solution and I simple get a response body of {
  "users": {}
}

Comment: Upon further investigation I see that the response is my Result (Output Mapping) for my Query in my data service

Comment: @KelishaGovender it looks like you are not getting any data from your Dataservice. First, isolate the Dataservice and figure out what request you need to get correct data from the Dataservice. Once you have figuredout how to invoke the Dataservice directly it's just a matter of replicating it in the API.

Comment: kindly note that when I invoke the data service it returns the correct first name and last name from my db, I have tested this directly on EI as well as postman, the issue that I am having is that I do not want the first and last name as a response, I want to be redirected to the links in the API, so my question is what do I need to change to get redirected instead of the first name and last name as a response.

Comment: If I pass a correct user code of Sash18, this is the response I get back from my data service, which is in accordance to my db.                                                                        
    {
    "users": {
        "user": [
            {
                "FirstName": "Sash",
                "LastName": "Test",
                "UserCode": "Sash18"
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: @KelishaGovender How are you passing it? As a query Param? Can you add the complete request URL you are using for the Dataservice?

Comment: I am passing a query param on postman I am using the following Get Http Request http://localhost:8280/services/rcsrest/Users?UserCode=Sash18 and on EI the request I am sending is <body>
   <p:_getusers xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/query2">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:UserCode xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/query2">Sash18</xs:UserCode>
   </p:_getcusers>
</body>

Comment: I have implemented both your updated data service and api and unfortunately the outcome is still the same, the response body is: {
  "users": {}
}

Comment: @KelishaGovender Enable wirelogs and check whether the outgoing request it correct. Refer https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/using-wire-logs/